# Call a javascript function dynamically in jquery dialog function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to call a function as parameter in jQuery dialog when the yes button is pressed. I am using the following code but this is not working.

```
function showYesNoAlertMsg(divId,optFunction){
 //window[optFunction].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
$('#'+divId).dialog('open');
$('#'+divId).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 175,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                 window[optFunction].apply(null, 
                                     Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function() {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
              });   
             }

       function newfunc(a,b){
            alert(a+'--'+b);
          }


       <input type="button" name="alert" id="alert" 
            onclick="showYesNoAlertMsg('boxDivId','newfunc','aaaaa','bbbbb');"/>

     <div id="boxDivId">
         hello
      </div>
```

When I click on the button named "alert" this the function `showYesNoAlertMsg` is called and it shows the dialog box of id "boxDivId" perfectly but I want to call a function named "newFunc" on the yes button. I passed this function as a parameter but it is not working in the dialog property. If I uncomment the first commented line in `showYesNoAlertMsg`, This line works fine and calls the function "newFunc" perfectly. but the same line is not working in Yes button. Please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In similar situation I had used such approach:

```
 function showYesNoAlertMsg(divId, optFunction, optFunctionParams) {
      if (!$.isArray(optFunctionParams)) {
           optFunctionParams = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
      }

      $('#' + divId).dialog({
           autoOpen: true,
           width: 400,
           height: 175,
           modal: true,
           resizable: false,
           buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                     if (optFunction && typeof optFunction == "function") {
                          optFunction.apply(window, optFunctionParams || []);
                     }
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function () {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                }
           }
      });
 }

 function newfunc(a, b) {
      alert(a + '--' + b);
 }

 <input type="button" name="alert" id="alert" value="Click Me"
      onclick="showYesNoAlertMsg('boxDivId', newfunc, ['aaaaa','bbbbb']);" />
```

If you want to use `arguments`, you need to cache it value in `showYesNoAlertMsg` context into some variable as in `Yes` button's click event handler it's already an arguments of this handler function